# which python IDE provide python console after running (Like Spyder)?

Tags: python, ide

I am looking for a good python IDE with powerful text editor like visual studio, atom, sublime which are able to provide console after running (like ipython).
Spyder is a good option but the text editor is not powerful.
Can you recommend me more? or how to do this in good text editor like Sublime?

Answer (score 2):

Two free IDE's

**1. Pycharm**

A good one, according to my colleague. Has an interactive python console. He is using community version

> https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

**2. Visual Code**

I'm using visual code with python extension. Works also fine. (Don't know about the interactive console thow)

> https://code.visualstudio.com/

You are able to debug python in both.